# Alternate If() function in Excel/OOCalc

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, openoffice-calc

Countless times over years, I've wanted to use an If statement in Excel/OpenOffice Calc in the form of:

```
If(A (comparison operator) B, A, C)
```

or, equivalently useful:

```
If(A (comparison operator) B, C, A)
```

where A is a very lengthy and convoluted expression, and B and C are short and simple, often (but not always) just a literal value. I've wanted a way to do one of these that didn't involve a duplicate A expression (which is at least twice as ugly, requires duplicate edits, and introduces entirely unnecessary mistakes which don't even manifest consistently), or giving A a dedicated cell, or using VBA (which is Microsoft proprietary, thus icky and not in Calc).

There are some workarounds for special cases, such as Iferr() in Excel (this is not in Calc), and manipulating numbers with 'conditional' type functions like Abs(), rounding and Mod(). But these are inadequate to do what I want most of the time (and the number manipulation is also inelegant and unclear). Is there any chance there's a function or simple series of functions which I've missed which can do this? It seems like a big thing to leave out.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do it without using an intermediate cell that serves no visible purpose. A lot of my sheets use functions, interactively, and are meant to be directly viewed. A hidden column can interfere with selecting, copying, and a hidden sheet makes things more complicated, including the references. (edit: I think, there was a comment in response to a comment which was deleted, then the response was deleted too.)

Comment: I'll add that this function would be especially useful when working with random numbers. For instance, sometimes I want to do something like draw numbers from a normal distribution but don't want any negative values. I'd like to flip the sign of any negative numbers drawn, but I can't place a condition on the drawn number in one cell because of this problem. `=IF(NORMINV(RAND(),1,0.3)<0,NORMINV(RAND(),1,0.3),NORMINV(RAND(),1,0.3)*-1)` doesn't work because the test and the result are different draws from the distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a LO Calc solution, i see two ways:

1. put the function that yields the result for `A` into a **separate, protected sheet**. This way, it's quite unlikely that the user accidentally tries to edit the cell holding your function. It has some other advantages:

   - no need for macro coding,
   - ability to copy the "function" sheet into other `ods` files,
   - simple to edit.
2. define the function as [**user-defined function**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/User-Defined_Functions) inside a basic macro. Star Basic used by LO Calc isn't the same as VBA, but it's quite similar, since both are Basic dialects. Advantages:

   - full power of starbasic language,
   - export it as "system library"
   - or embed into `ods` templates.

Creating a user-defined function in Calc is very easy. Assuming you'll have to calculate value `A` by multiplying three different values, you would simply create a macro like this:

```vba
Function A(b, c, d)
A = b*c*d
End Function
```

Now, you can use that function inside your `If` expression:

```basic
If(A(4, 5, 6) > B, A(4, 5, 6), C)
```

Of course, this simple example doesn't make much sense, but it is more useful if your code to calculate `A()` gets more complex. If the three values to multiply are fixed, you can reduce the code to

```basic
Function A()
A = 4*5*6
End Function
```

and call it simpy using

```basic
If(A() > B, A(), C)
```

I know these examples are just too simple to illustrate the solution. Just think of adding definitions of constants or creating a complete function library inside a macro, maybe with "private" helper functions invisible to the user that just edits the `ods` sheet.

Answer (score 3):

User tohuwawohu posted an answer that led me directly to mine. I don't think tohuwawohu quite understood what I wanted, perhaps through my fault, but his macro suggestion helped me to understand. I just made a macro, which is now loaded into all sheets and which defined a function that I can call with the same syntax as a built-in function.

But, for one thing I'm using OpenOffice Calc, not LibreOffice Calc, but they're both using a BASIC language that's very similar to VBA (Visual Basic for Applications, by Microsoft, as used in Excel).

You can define chunks of statements via Sub (as in subroutine) and Function. According to [this page in the documentation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Using_a_macro_as_a_function), loading/running a macro with a Function in it does just that, lets you call it as a function in ordinary cell formulas. This is a fact that I wasn't aware of before, despite trying to find a way to do this in the past.

After browsing the [OOCalc Basic overview](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Branching) for a bit, I made a function that works, though not quite as I'd like since the operator and second operand are passed as two separate arguments, and the former as a string. But, I recall there was once at least one Excel built-in function that used the same, an argument for an operator passed as a string, so at least there's precedent.

I guess, the issue was that I didn't know it was so simple to make a "macro" that, instead of executing some code and leaving, defined a function which you could call in cell formulas. The word "macro" kind of threw me off, since usually it only means procedural type things, plus there was info from the "User Manual" about calling these functions-in-macros, which was in a different part of the site than the Basic overview.

Tools > Macros > Organize Macros > OpenOffice Basic > "Organizer..." button > Libraries tab > My Macros & Dialogs > "Standard" Library > Edit button

I pasted this at the end, saved and closed the editor. It performs the second of the two functions in the original question, but in the form IfAlt(A, operator, B, C), where operator is a string of a comparison operator. If A op B is true, returns C, otherwise returns A.

```
Function IfAlt(arg1, op, arg2, ifTrue)
    If (op="=" AND arg1=arg2) OR (op="<>" AND arg1<>arg2) OR _
        (op=">" AND arg1>arg2) OR (op=">=" AND arg1>=arg2) OR _
        (op="<" AND arg1<arg2) OR (op="<=" AND arg1<=arg2) Then
        IfAlt = ifTrue
    Else
        IfAlt = arg1
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this, but i'm going to take a try to see if this is what you mean.  So i'm going to use Excel as an example, since i have it and not as familiar with OpenOffice Calc.

In Excel, i know you would put `=if(condition, if true, if false)` for the if function, and if i understand you correctly, you are just wanting to consolidate it into a smaller function so it's easier to read, right?

The only way to do it would be to use a cell for each one, because of how Excel works, there isn't a way to declare a variable without using a cell.  You could use VBA, but as you mentioned, you can't use that in openoffice.  The problem is that you have to be able to store the formula/value/etc. somewhere, which is why it has to be a cell.

I don't know your situation, but you would have to protect the worksheet and lock the fields, mark them hidden, or leave them alone and hope for the best.